# Feasible to store video in Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

There were so many questions asked with the same question, but now its 2015 and they might be outdated. I just want to make sure, whether its still correct to do or not?

In my app, I'll have 20 to 25 videos should be available even if user is offline. I'll download it when user played it for the first time. I'm not sure what is the correct & accurate way to store this? Yes, those videos will not be more than of 15mins. And I think each of one would be of size around (approx.) 15-25MBs.

Most of the answers suggested to store it as external file? Is it feasible? Is there any other good way?

I'm planning to use core data in my app. Still development isn't started so it will be on me to choose best thing to store data.

Please suggest.

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest storing your videos in Library directory (as files) or something. If you want to use core data I suggest you store file path only but not video data (and I don't think its possible but it would be dirty :) )

Comment: All is the same even for now. There is no need to store videos in db. You can store video titles or their hashes as unique ids. Of course U can store BLOBs ("Binary Large OBjects" such as image and sound data),but It is better, however, if you are able to store BLOBs as resources on the filesystem